# trying to webscrape a website but getting 403 forbidden

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-scraping

I'm trying to access ticketmasters website to get prices of events.

However i'm running into issues where httpparty returns a 403 error on trying to scrape the website

This is all i have

```
page = HTTParty.get(ticketmaster_url)
 doc = Nokogiri::HTML(page)
```

And the 403 appears on the get call

Thanks
Sam

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you are using `HTTParty` here. You can simply opne and parse the page usign [Nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/parsing_an_html_xml_document.html#from_the_internets):

```
require 'open-uri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(ticketmaster_url))
```

where `ticketmaster_url` is the url of the page you want to extract information from.

Comment: Ive done the above and get this error `OpenURI::HTTPError (403 Forbidden):`

Comment: Have you imported the open-uri library at the top of your file like I've shown in my answer ?

Comment: Also verify that ticketmaster_url is of type string like so: "http://m.ticketmaster.com/ticket/events.do;jsessionid=AYvXsNLTwg1JGnjiue0OJ0Ki.web4?region=35"

Comment: Yep thats there, Wouldn't have gotten the 403 without the open would i?

Comment: I've tried adding user agent onto it, Which hasn't done anything. The url is correct as it works through my local machine fine. Wonder if its because ticketmaster might be blocking the ip of my server?

Comment: Don't suppose you know of a way around this ?

Comment: One thing I've done in the pass to avoid getting blocked is I passed though a proxy server when making requests. Another solution would be to dynamically change your IP address but hay can be tedious...

Comment: There are lists of free proxies out there (they might be slow though) just google it and you'll find a bunch pretty easily. In terms of managing the proxies and setting up the right agent I would recommend using the Mechanize gem. Take a look at it and let me know what you think :)

Comment: i've been looking, Not sure a proxy is the best way to go about ti :( They seem way to slow!

Comment: I agree! Another thing you could do is pause between each request your are making to the ticketmaster server. That way you aren't over calling their endpoint